# Xib file Linkage and WebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I got a problem that is going on for a week now, i have a webView that i set up, but the xib file doesn't want to link with my controller, i know there is a topic about that but i'm new to objective c and i don't understand a damn thing and i rather want to do it programmatically if someone can show me or help me please.

here is my code :

.h
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
 IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
-(void)PushView;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "MyWebViewController.h"


@interface ViewController()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myWebView = _myWebview;

-(void)viewDidLoad;
{

    myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    myWebView.delegate = self;

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *defaults = [prefs stringForKey:@"myKey"];
    NSString *defaults2 = [prefs stringForKey:@"mySecondKey"];

    NSString *username = defaults;
    NSString *password = defaults2;
    NSLog(defaults);

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

    NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&password=%@", username, password];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

    [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

@end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your webview is conrrectly linked, you don't need to allocate it again.

You need to use the self. to access the variable. Use self.mywebView or _mywebView, but myWebView is pointing to an empty variable.

Also, use [super viewDidLoad] at the beggining of the method;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myWebView.delegate = self;

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *defaults = [prefs stringForKey:@"myKey"];
    NSString *defaults2 = [prefs stringForKey:@"mySecondKey"];

    NSString *username = defaults;
    NSString *password = defaults2;
    NSLog(defaults);

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

    NSString* body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&password=%@", username, password];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

    [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

If you want to check that the webview is linked, put a breakpoint at the beggining of the method and see the value of myWebView.